# Check that you can see a text with a class in functional testing / Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I need to check that my text exists in my page with PHPUnit / Laravel.

```
  <del class="text-muted">Configure</del>
```

Right now, I know only how to check that Configure exists with

```
 $this->visit('/')
        ->see('configure')
```

Is it posible to check that there is a Configure text with a text-muted class in Laravel 5.2 Built in Tests???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is:

```
 $this->visit('/')
      ->seeInElement("del.text-muted", 'Configure'));
```

But I didn't find it in official doc :(